# Return string array in C

Tags: c, arrays, string

I am using .lib file created by third party application.The Header file listed all functions used in that Lib file. Using .lib file, am reading from and writing values to that application. They have different methods to read and write integer values,decimal values and strings. This methods are defined in C Language. Unfortunately i don't have any detail documentation for those methods. I used the method for retrieving the integers and decimal values. I got the problem when i use the method to return string value.

For example , in the lib.h file ,the methods names like

```
int GetIntData(char *Var, int *data);
int GetDecData(char *Var, double*data);
int GetDataString(char *aName, char*data , int size);
```

Here Var- indicates name of the variable which holds the value. If i want to get the value of the pump switch status. I use the below method

```
int value;    
GetIntData("PUMP1",&value);
    int status = value;
```

The same way i can get decimal data and also string. I need to get the name  of the pump which is stored in PUMPN variable. I tried this

```
char *sData;
GetDataString("PUMPN ",&sData,10);
```

But during compilation, it shows error as

```
cannot convert parameter 2 from 'char **' to 'char *'
```

So i tried this

```
char *sData;
    GetDataString("PUMPN ",sData,10);
```

It doesn't show error during compilation,but while executing it abruptly stopped by saying 'the application not working' May be the error handling is not properly defined in that .lib file.

Just i want to make sure whether the problem is from my side. Is that the way to use char pointer for string?

Comment: Your sData variable needs some space to store data in. Either call malloc() or change it from being a pointer to being an array.

Comment: Please post a full example with the whole function.

Comment: doest "sample" have to be written in sData?

Comment: I have not downvoted your question but I will try to give you some tips on how to improve it (doing the downvoter's job here): 1. Fix the spelling formatting - this is not nitpicking it greatly improves the reader's experience and also demonstrates better attitude 2. When saying you get some exception always include the actual exception - we are not THAT good at guessing 3. Provide minimal code sample enough to reproduce the observed behavior

Comment: I **guess** that `size` is the `data`size. So you could try to use the function that way `char sData[10]; GetDataString("SAMPLE", sData, sizeof data);`. But you should add the `GetDataString` function documentation to make a better question...

Comment: please post understandable questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue with following :

```
char *sData;
GetDataString("PUMPN ",&sData,10);
But during compilation, it shows error as
```

GetDataString expect char* and by passing &sData you are passing char** as sData is already a char*.

Issue with following :

```
char *sData;
GetDataString("PUMPN ",sData,10);
```

you are correctly passing char* to GetDataString but as you are not assigning any memory you are seeing crash ,to solve do something like this :

```
char *sData = malloc(10);
GetDataString("PUMPN ",sData,10);
```

**note** : you need to check what should be the expected size of buffer that GetDataString expect and pass that much buffer size to it.

Comment: It works..ha..ha.. first i got error as "cannot convert from 'void *' to 'char *'         Conversion from 'void*' to pointer to non-'void' requires an explicit cast" ..then i changed 'char *sData = (char *)malloc(10);'. it worked. Thanks

Comment: you need to include <stdlib.h> .there is no need typecast while doing malloc.

Comment: @Paresh Dhandhukiya "you need to check what should be the expected size of buffer that GetDataString expect and pass that much buffer size to it." the length of "PUMPN " is the expected size

Answer (score -1):

If i understood correctly `GetDataString` writes `"SAMPLE"` in `sData`.
First you have to allocate memory fo sData.

```
sData = malloc(strlen("SAMPLE") + 1);
```

and call the function like this

```
GetDataString("SAMPLE",sData,strlen("SAMPLE"));
```

Comment: assuming the tag has the same length as the data it tags

Comment: I was not the one down voting but in my comment I am referring to it is I found your example a bit confusing, one gets the impression that "SAMPLE" has something to do with what comes back in sData but there is no telling how long the data is that GetDataString wants to retrieve. I think `,sData, sizeof(sData)` where `sData` is an array would be clearer. Just my 2c.

Comment: sData could be an array, but only if VLA is supported.That's why i prefer to use the heap for such cases.